# Category Products not showing on frontend after Magento update

Tags: category-products, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.6

Updated Magento to the latest 2.4.6 and now the products do not show on the category pages, I can view the individual products and they show on the left filter, but no on the page. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: did you run indexer? clear flush cache try on incognito browser, check all logs like exceptions, keep in mind when you run indexer check carefully all indexers are successfully ran.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I ran reindexer and elasticsearch running perfectly, found out the problem was depreciated code within the template.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the elasticsearch... I think your elasticsearch service is off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reindex your catalog: After a Magento update, it is possible that your catalog indexes may have become corrupted or outdated. To fix this issue, you can try reindexing your catalog. Go to System > Index Management in your Magento admin panel and click the "Reindex All" button.
2. Check the product settings: Make sure that the products you are trying to display are set to "Enabled" and are assigned to the correct category. Go to Catalog > Products in your Magento admin panel and verify that the products are in the correct category and are set to "Enabled".
3. Check the category settings: Make sure that the category settings are configured correctly. Go to Catalog > Manage Categories in your Magento admin panel and select the category in question. Verify that the "Display Mode" setting is set to "Products" and that the "Is Active" setting is set to "Yes".
4. Clear your cache: Clearing your Magento cache can often resolve display issues on the frontend. Go to System > Cache Management in your Magento admin panel and click the "Flush Magento Cache" button.